# Amazon Product API: Obtaining PPC Keywords by ASIN

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-scraping, amazon-product-api

I am trying to find PPC keywords by ASIN number. There are some tools do this, and when I tried this tool, It works for every ASIN. These tools give some details like below;

- PPC keyword
- History highest position (Page 1 Top Position 1 / Page 2 Top Position
  2 etc.), Estimated monthly search volume,
- Average number of reviews of products listed on the 1st page,
- Average rating of products listed on the 1st page,
- Average price (after applying discounts) of products listed on the
  1st page,
- Score calculated based on big data, the higher the score is, the more
  recommended the keyword is,
- Suggested Bid (Broad ($1.59 1 - 2.54), Phrase ($2.25 1.82 - 2.54),
  Exact ($2.25 1.82 - 5.36))

[Result List](https://i.hizliresim.com/p6aMaN.png)

Can I get these details from Amazon Product API or Advertising API directly?

Comment: Have you found an answer to your question ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the above required data from H10 and JS tools

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).